# Mathematica - Maximizing a Function Over an Interval

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a function which I would like to maximize over an independent variable range, say a->b. How would I do this in Mathematica? The documentation does not provide an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions you are looking for are [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Maximize.html) and [`NMaximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NMaximize.html) (similarly, there is [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Minimize.html) and [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NMinimize.html)). Since you do not provide any details about the function itself, I shall call it `f` and assume that it takes one variable. Then to maximize over a given range, you specify both the function and the range, as follows

```
Maximize[{ f[x], a <= x <= b}, x]
```

or, if symbolic maximization is difficult to do, you can have it numerically maximized using the same form

```
NMaximize[{ f[x], a <= x <= b}, x]
```

For minimization, replace as appropriate.

Comment: It seems that `NMaximize` will often give you results out of the specified bounds. Are there any ways to force it to stay within them, other than changing the function value to be highly negative outside?

Comment: Here is one: https://pastebin.com/Tn7VVaCF It gives me `by -> -0.088` even though there is a requirement `0 < by`. I even gave it some starting ranges within the bounds, since otherwise it didn't return an answer at all.

Comment: @ThomasAhle thanks. It's a known bug in "simplifying" simultaneous inequalities to improve their calculability. The recommended workaround is to use a function that returns something very far below 0 when the parameters are outside the range, e.g. `NMaximize[{If[
   0.3` <= bx <= 0.4` && 0.2` <= by <= 0.3` && 0.1` <= b1 <= 0.2` && 
    0.` <= b2 <= 0.1`, 
   Log[b1/bx]/Log[b2/bx] - 
    Log[b1/(bx + by - b1)]/Log[b2/(bx + by - b2)], -10.^25], 
  0 < b2 < b1 && b1 < by < bx && 
   bx + by < 
    1 + b2}, {{bx, .3, .4}, {by, .2, .3}, {b1, .1, .2}, {b2, .0, .1}}]`.

Comment: @ThomasAhle cont'd, which on my machine returns `{0.0728101, {bx -> 0.367874, by -> 0.20006, b1 -> 0.199981, b2 -> 0.0999925}}`, plus the message `NMaximize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.` I also tried returning `-Infinity`, but `-10.^25` works better.